# How to maximize correlation by sampling using R

Tags: r, string, sequence, correlation, sampling

I have the following reference sequence:

```
reference_seq <- "KPAACQHRQDKWKNSHWNRFKAYFVVIKKK"
```

With this function that simply calculate the composition of amino acid sequence:

```
calculate_aa_content <- function (x) 
{

  AADict <- c("A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H", 
              "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V")
  AAC <- summary(factor(strsplit(x, split = "")[[1]], levels = AADict), 
                 maxsum = 21)/nchar(x)
  AAC
}
```

I can get the AA composition of the reference sequence:

```
> calculate_aa_content(reference_seq)
         A          R          N          D          C          E 
0.10000000 0.06666667 0.06666667 0.03333333 0.03333333 0.00000000 
         Q          G          H          I          L          K 
0.06666667 0.00000000 0.06666667 0.03333333 0.00000000 0.23333333 
         M          F          P          S          T          W 
0.00000000 0.06666667 0.03333333 0.03333333 0.00000000 0.06666667 
         Y          V 
0.03333333 0.06666667
```

Then I have the seed sequence:

```
seed          <- "FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAK??????????"
```

What I want to do is to sample 10aa represented by 10 question marks (?) from 20 amino acid vector here:

```
 AADict <- c("A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H", 
                  "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V")
```

So that the Pearson correlation of final constructed sequence from seed  with reference sequence is maximized (allowing certain number of iterations if not possible to get absolute max).

For example one of the sample from seed sampling, could be:

```
> sample_1 <- "FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAKHHHHHHHHHH"
> cor(calculate_aa_content(reference_seq), calculate_aa_content(sample_1))
[1] 0.2955238
```

But the correlation is low. What I'd like to do is to find max correlation of constructed string from seed with reference sequence after certain number of iteration.

An additional feature with  early stopping if the difference with current maximum is within certain threshold, say 0.01, would be appreciated.

Note that the final sequence *should not* be the same with reference squence.

How can achieve that efficiently with R?

Comment: Just replace the `?` by the characters in the reference seq? It gives me a correlation of 0.7812744.

Comment: @RuiBarradas How do you know if that is the max one? I mean does replacing ? with characters in ref seq always gives the max one? for any given pair of ref and seed?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't. Wrong assumption, see my answer with a counter-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function to simulate new sequences and compute the correlation. Then call the function `R` times, get the `cor` components and find the maximum.

```r
calculate_aa_content <- function (x) {
  AADict <- c("A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H", 
              "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V")
  AAC <- summary(factor(strsplit(x, split = "")[[1]], levels = AADict), 
                 maxsum = 21)/nchar(x)
  AAC
}

fun <- function(x, ref, dict = AADict) {
  i <- regexpr("\\?", x)
  n <- nchar(x) - i + 1L
  new <- sample(dict, n, TRUE)
  new <- paste(new, collapse = "")
  substring(x, i) <- new
  list(
    new = x,
    cor = cor(calculate_aa_content(ref), calculate_aa_content(x))
  )
}

reference_seq <- "KPAACQHRQDKWKNSHWNRFKAYFVVIKKK"
seed <- "FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAK??????????"

AADict <- c("A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H", 
            "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V")

set.seed(2022)
R <- 1e4
res <- replicate(R, fun(seed, reference_seq), simplify = FALSE)
cor_vec <- sapply(res, `[[`, 'cor')
res[which.max(cor_vec)]
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$new
#> [1] "FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAKKKWYKEKWFN"
#> 
#> [[1]]$cor
#> [1] 0.7902037
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

In the event that there are more than one value equal to the maximum, use instead

```
res[cor_vec == max(cor_vec)]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there a way to make the iteration to stop early if the difference with current maximum is within certain threshold (say 0.01).

Comment: @littleworth No, not with `replicate`. With a `for` loop, yes, but it could stop if, say at the 2nd iteration, you have `0.010` and `0.015`. Very far from the maximum. In fact, the output could be anything

Comment: why can't your code take this pattern `"FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTHLAK????RTRHLAK"`? It yields this as its new sequence `"FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTHLAKWKNKYCFNAWF"`.

In that example, the sampling need to be done only for ???? (4 ?) in the middle.

How can I modify your code so that it can generalize to seed with any position of `?`.  Other example include `????HIDVKDRHRTHLAKKKKRTRHLAK` or `KDRH?THLAKKKKRT?HLAK`

Comment: I opened a new question specifically for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162714/how-to-replace-the-wild-card-characters-with-sampled-characters-in-r

Comment: @littleworth Answered [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74165036/8245406).

Comment: care to look at this question (exact solution version)?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74181792/how-to-find-optimal-string-content-that-minimizes-the-mse-of-character-count-vec