# How to replace the wild card characters with sampled characters in R

Tags: r, string

I have the following sequence:

```
s0 <- "KDRH?THLA???RT?HLAK"
```

The wild card character there is indicated by `?`.
What I want to do is to replace that character by sampled character from this vector:

```
AADict <- c("A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H", 
            "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V")
```

Since `s0` has 5 wild cards `?`, I would sample from AADict:

```
set.seed(1)
nof_wildcard <- 5
tolower(sample(AADict, nof_wildcard, TRUE))
```

Which gives `[1] "d" "q" "a" "r" "l"`

Hence the expected result is:

```
     KDRH?THLA???RT?HLAK
     KDRHdTHLAqarRTlHLAK
```

So the placement of the sampled character must be exactly in the same position as `?`, but the order of the character is not important.
e.g. this answer is also acceptable: `KDRHqTHLAdlaRTrHLAK`.

How can I achieve that with R?

The other example are:

```
s1 <- "FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTHLAK????RTRHLAK"
s2 <- "FKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAK??????????"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split your string in single characters which makes it easy to replace the wildcard without the need of a loop (was my first approach):

```r
replace_wc <- function(x, dict) {
  x <- strsplit(x, split = "")[[1]]
  ix <- grepl("\\?", x)
  x[ix] <- sample(dict, sum(ix), replace = TRUE)

  return(paste0(x, collapse = ""))
}

s0 <- "KDRH?THLA???RT?HLAK"
AADict <- c(
  "A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H",
  "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V"
)

set.seed(1)

replace_wc(s0, tolower(AADict))
#> [1] "KDRHdTHLAqarRTlHLAK"
```

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to replace the "?" characters 'one at a time' using a loop, e.g.

```r
s0 <- "KDRH?THLA???RT?HLAK"
AADict <- c("A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H", 
            "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V")
s0
#> [1] "KDRH?THLA???RT?HLAK"
repeat{s0 <- sub("\\?", sample(tolower(AADict), 1), s0); if(grepl("\\?", s0) == FALSE) break}
s0
#> [1] "KDRHtTHLAidwRTyHLAK"

s1 <- "FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTHLAK????RTRHLAK"
repeat{s1 <- sub("\\?", sample(tolower(AADict), 1), s1); if(grepl("\\?", s1) == FALSE) break}
s1
#> [1] "FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTHLAKrstaRTRHLAK"

s2 <- "FKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAK??????????"
repeat{s2 <- sub("\\?", sample(tolower(AADict), 1), s2); if(grepl("\\?", s2) == FALSE) break}
s2
#> [1] "FKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAKdvcfmheiqn"
```

---

Another approach which can also allow for sampling without replacement:

```r
s0 <- "KDRH?THLA???RT?HLAK"
AADict <- c("A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H", 
            "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V")
matches <- gregexpr("\\?", s0)
regmatches(s0, matches) <- lapply(lengths(matches), sample, x = tolower(AADict), replace = FALSE)
s0
#> [1] "KDRHdTHLAlanRTiHLAK"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Here is a vectorized function to replace the `"?"` characters in a vector of strings.

```r
fun <- function(x, dict = AADict) {
  dict <- tolower(dict)
  inx <- gregexpr("\\?", x)
  sapply(seq_along(x), \(j) {
    for(i in inx[[j]]) {
      substr(x[j], i, i) <- sample(dict, 1L)
    }
    x[j]
  })
}

AADict <- c("A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H", 
            "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V")

s0 <- "KDRH?THLA???RT?HLAK"
s1 <- "FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTHLAK????RTRHLAK"
s2 <- "FKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAK??????????"

fun(s0)
#> [1] "KDRHsTHLAwppRTwHLAK"

fun(s1)
#> [1] "FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTHLAKyfqfRTRHLAK"

fun(s2)
#> [1] "FKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAKnsfehqwmkv"

fun(c(s0, s1, s2))
#> [1] "KDRHiTHLAdssRTgHLAK"            "FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTHLAKcdivRTRHLAK"
#> [3] "FKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAKfrpafwpnif"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>