# How to find optimal string content that minimizes the MSE of character count vectors with its reference string

Tags: r, string, algorithm, optimization, combinatorics

I have the following reference sequence:

```
ref_seq      <- "MGHQQLYWSHPRKFGQGSRSCRVTSNRHGLIRKYGLNMSRQSFR"
```

and this seed pattern string:

```
seed_pattern <- "FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAK??????????"
```

There are 10 wildcards (?) in that pattern.

Given this functions:

```
aa_count_normalized <- function(x) {
  AADict <- c(
    "A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H",
    "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V"
  )
  AAC <- summary(factor(strsplit(x, split = "")[[1]], levels = AADict),
                 maxsum = 21
  ) / nchar(x)
  AAC
}

aa_count <- function(x) {
  AADict <- c(
    "A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H",
    "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V"
  )
  AAC <- summary(factor(strsplit(x, split = "")[[1]], levels = AADict),
                 maxsum = 21
  ) 
  AAC
}
```

I can get :

```
# we need to normalize refseq_aa content with respect
# to the length of seed_pattern, to accommodate the length
# difference between the two.
> refseq_aa_content <- aa_count_normalized(ref_seq) * nchar(seed_pattern) 
> refseq_aa_content
        A         R         N         D         C         E 
0.0000000 4.7727273 1.3636364 0.0000000 0.6818182 0.0000000 
        Q         G         H         I         L         K 
2.7272727 3.4090909 2.0454545 0.6818182 2.0454545 1.3636364 
        M         F         P         S         T         W 
1.3636364 1.3636364 0.6818182 4.0909091 0.6818182 0.6818182 
        Y         V 
1.3636364 0.6818182
```

What I want to do is to replace the wild cards of the `seed pattern` - while keeping the non-wildcards as it is -  with combinations of residue taken from:

```
 AADict <- c(
        "A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H",
        "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V"
      )
```

such that the mean squared error (MSE) of the final amino acid count of the seed sequence and the *normalized* reference sequence count is minimized.

With this MSE function:

```
mse <- function (ref, new_seq) {
  return(mean((ref - new_seq)^2))
}
```

and with this final seed sequences:

```
seed_final.1 <- aa_count("FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAKRQQGGGSSSY")
seed_final.2 <- aa_count("FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAKRQQQGGGSSY")
seed_final.3 <- aa_count("FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAKSSSGGGRRQQ") # onyambu's
```

I get

```
> mse(refseq_aa_content, seed_final.1 )
[1] 1.501446
> mse(refseq_aa_content, seed_final.2 )
[1] 1.63781
> mse(refseq_aa_content, seed_final.3 )
[1] 1.560537
```

The `seed_final.1` is the *optimal exact solution*, because it has the lowest MSE. Namely the 10 `?`s is to be replaced with:

```
G Q R S Y 
3 2 1 3 1 (total 10)
```

How can I create an efficient R code to return `FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAKRQQGGGSSSY`
as the answer.

Comment: Your optimal solution is technically not optimal. The sequence `"FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAKSSSGGGRRQQ"` for example has a lower `mse` than what you have

Comment: Indeed, why bother with 2 `Y`, when you're missing 6 `S`, 5 `G`, 4 `R`, and 4 `Q`? Reduce the largest difference first.

Comment: @onyambu Thanks for your comment. I updated my OP. What I meant specifically is minimizing the *normalized AA count*. I included your example in my OP. My initial answer still holds `FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAKRQQGGGSSSY`. 
We need to normalized them it is because the length of ref_seq and seed_pattern is different.

Comment: @Dialecticus Thanks for your comment. I updated my OP to clarify and my final answer still holds. Please advice how would you go about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can model your problem as integer quadratic problem where you want to minimize:

`sum(r^2) - 2 sum(z * r)`

with constraints:

`sum(r) = k`

`r[i] nonegative integer`

where:

- `r[i]` how many ith letters of `AADict` you need to add to `seed_pattern`
- `z[i] = n(y)/n(x) * x[i] - y[i]`
- `x[i]` counts of ith letter of `AADict` in `ref_seq`
- `y[i]` counts of ith letter of `AADict` in `seed_pattern`
- `n(x)` number of characters in `ref_seq`
- `n(y)` number of charecters in `seed_pattern`
- `k` number of wild card characters in `seed_pattern`

I din't manage to find mixed-integer quadratic solver in R (free one) so here is heuristic using `DEoptimR`:

```
ref_seq <- "MGHQQLYWSHPRKFGQGSRSCRVTSNRHGLIRKYGLNMSRQSFR"
seed_pattern <- "FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAK??????????"

AADict <- c(
  "A", "R", "N", "D", "C", "E", "Q", "G", "H",
  "I", "L", "K", "M", "F", "P", "S", "T", "W", "Y", "V"
)

aminoSummary <- function(x){
  
  f <- factor(strsplit(x, split = "")[[1]], levels = AADict)
  
  list(
    l = nchar(x),
    k = sum(is.na(f)),
    z = table(f)
  )
}

x <- aminoSummary(ref_seq)
y <- aminoSummary(seed_pattern)

M <- length(AADict)

res <- DEoptimR::JDEoptim(
  lower = rep(0, M),
  upper = rep(y$k, M) + 1,
  fn = function(r, z, k){
    r <- floor(r)
    sum(r * r) - 2 * sum(z * r)
  },
  constr = function(r, z, k) sum(floor(r)) - k,
  meq = 1,
  z = as.vector(x$z * y$l / x$l - y$z),
  k = y$k
)

rep(AADict, floor(res$par))
[1] "R" "Q" "Q" "G" "G" "G" "S" "S" "S" "Y"
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I've awarded you 50 bounty!  How did you derive that the cost function we want to minimize is `sum(r^2) - 2 sum(z * r)` ?

Comment: just write what is your goal: you want to add (replace all ?) letters to `y` so that square error is minimum. So you want to minimize `sum((x/n(x) - (y+r)/n(y))^2)`.  Now you just simplify that function in regard to the optimization.